# Error while building GremlinPlugin for Neo4j Server

Tags: django, maven, neo4j, gremlin, neo4django

I try to explore how neo4j could be integrated with django project and launch admin page in my django project with dependence on [neo4django](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django). But seems it requires GremlinPlugin extension in neo4j server.

Using [this documentation](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin#building-from-source-and-deploying-into-neo4j-server) I try to build jar file for GremlinPlugin.

But already on the first step I have error with absent license header:

```
alx@x1:~/Downloads/gremlin-plugin$ mvn -e clean package 
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building neo4j-gremlin-plugin 2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ neo4j-gremlin-plugin ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) @ neo4j-gremlin-plugin ---
[INFO] Checking licenses...
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/site/site.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/rest/GremlinConsoleServiceTest.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/rest/ConfigureEnabledManagementConsolesGremlinTest.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/assembly/docs-assembly.xml
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/assembly/server-plugin.xml
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/repr/GremlinObjectToRepresentationConverter.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/repr/GremlinTableRepresentation.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/repr/GremlinMapRepresentation.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/GremlinPlugin.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/CountingEngineReplacementDecision.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/EngineReplacementDecision.java
Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/GremlinPluginTest.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/ScriptCountingEngineReplacementDecision.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/console/Neo4jGroovyImports.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/console/GremlinSessionCreator.java
[INFO] [INFO] [INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/test/resources/graphml.xml
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/console/GremlinSessionTest.java
Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/console/GremlinWebConsole.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/console/GremlinResultHook.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/webadmin/console/GremlinSession.java
Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/GremlinPluginFunctionalTest.java
[INFO] Missing header in: /home/alx/Downloads/gremlin-plugin/src/data/graphml1.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.864s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 14 21:58:25 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/302M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-gremlin-plugin: Some files do not have the expected license header -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-gremlin-plugin: Some files do not have the expected license header
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some files do not have the expected license header
    at com.google.code.mojo.license.LicenseCheckMojo.execute(LicenseCheckMojo.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I use maven of version 3.0.4:

```
alx@x1:~/Downloads/gremlin-plugin$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.0-35-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Does anybody has ideas what causes this problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: When did you pull from the repository? Try again.

Comment: Michael, Seems my pull from master already not the freshest one (I've stucked with problem about a day ago). But your last commit(-s) made the magic! Thank you!

Should I delete the question or mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was in pulling source code of the last commit ([this one](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin/commit/4bb3a41867b4b94bba0d5f62fcadf12a79f566e5) at the moment of writing). Thanks to [Michael Hunger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728812/michael-hunger) for rapid response!